# Magento ver 1.14.2.2 exception 'Quote totals must be collected before this operation'

Tags: php, magento

I've upgraded latest Magento EE version 1.14.2.2. When I proceed to checkout, last step I press button Place Order, it redirects to cart page. Here's log exception:

```
exception 'Exception' with message 'Quote totals must be collected before this operation.' in /home/beadahol/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php:1861
Stack trace:
#0 /home/Project/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(326): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->prepareRecurringPaymentProfiles()
#1 /home/Project/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(223): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->_submitRecurringPaymentProfiles()
#2 /home/Project/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(238): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitNominalItems()
#3 /home/Project/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(812): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#4 /home/Project/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(583): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveOrder()
#5 /home/Project/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveOrderAction()
#6 /home/Project/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#7 /home/Project/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#8 /home/Project/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#9 /home/Project/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#10 /home/Project/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#11 {main}
```

I don't modify or overwrite file Quote.php. This error only occurred web server, on local still works well.

Based on research internet [in this link](https://journalxtra.com/magento/quote-totals-must-be-collected-before-this-operation-blah-blah-blah-what-a-pita-you-are-magento/) they show ' the problem was finally solved by the switch to SuPHP (PHP handler)'. (My server configure Apache to run PHP as FastCGI)

Does anyone have a same issue on Magento 1.14.2.2? Please give me the solution to result this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. What worked for me was i went to the database << table 'core_config_data' and changed the values for path 'design/email/header' and 'design/email/footer' from '2' to '0'.

Worked for me !!

Comment: How is this related tho?  can you explain a little?